# How can I get a site collection object from Sharepoint server

Tags: java, apache, sharepoint, tomcat, sharepoint-2010

I am stuck up in a problem wherein I need to query a sharepoint server to return all the sites(top sites) present at the same level. For example, If I query sharepoint server to return all the top sites which are at the same level as that of "http://vmsp2010-1", it should return all top sites. I have a web server implemented in Java which is hosted on the Apache Tomcat server. From this web server, I need to query sharepoint server to return all the top sites which are at the same level in sharepoint. Please let me know How I could query the sharepoint server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think SharePoint's OOB Web Services supports what you are looking for. Possibly, you would want to create a custom web service of yours and get the list of site collections. You will have to write the code using SharePoint Object Model and host this logic inside a custom web service.

Comment: Could you please help me in giving pointers for the sample program(a very basic program) to query the SharePoint server in C#.NET. I have decided to write the web service to do the above said job in C#.NET. I will build my knowledge based on the pointers that you provide. Thanks, Rajath